# How to compare values of rows and columns of two text files in bash?

Tags: awk

I have two text files and I want to compare their correspondent values according to their rows and columns. By comparing, I mean to check if the values are equal and `echo` if the values are the same or not. Here are the files:

file1.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row1  1     4     7        
row2  2     5     8         
row3  3     6     9
```

file2.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row2  1     4     11        
row1  2     5     12
```

Here are the constraints:

- compare only the rows that exist (ie: since row3 exists in file1.txt but not in file2.txt, no comparison is needed)
- comparing has to be done one row and one column at a time.
- must use `awk`
- the rows may be out of order in the files

I am thinking of something like this:

```
awk 'NR>2
    for (i=2;i<NR;i++)              #for each row of file1.txt
    {     
        for(j=1;i<NF;j++)           #for each column of file1.txt
        {
             // check if row and column of file1.txt is equal to row and column of file2.txt
        } 
    }

' file1.txt file2.txt
```

I am a beginner in bash so please excuse all my errors. Is something like this possible? Also how do you compare values of two different text files? Thanks. Let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: Certainly are a lot of constraints... I would use this as some kind of exercise in an academic setting.

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: No I am not. I just couldn't figure out what exact output OP is trying to get from this question.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly this is a homework problem, so I'll just give you some tips. You must have an awk book to read where you can learn the details.

The way you're trying to use NR is incorrect. It is not the total number of records, but the number of the current record.

Remember that an awk script is a list of rules, each with the form `pattern {actions}`. So your program should take that form as much as possible. awk's basic mechanism is to read a record, test it against each rule's pattern in turn, if it matches a pattern then execute the associated actions, when it reaches the end of the rules go on to the next record. It's "data driven", which is very different from a language like C or Java, for instance.

You can skip the first two lines of both files with an initial rule like this:

```
FNR < 3 { next }  # if file record number < 3, go to next record
```

There is an idiomatic way to deal with two files. NR == FNR will only be true in the first file, since NR (record number) keeps incrementing across files whereas FNR (file record number) is reset between files. So you can do this:

```
NR == FNR {
    # Only the first file's records will be processed here

    next  # go on to the next record
}
```

While processing the first file, you'll want to use an associative array to save the records, keyed by the first field.

The final rule will deal only with the second file, testing if the first field is a key in the associative array, and if it is, comparing the other fields to see if they match.

So your program might have this structure:

```
FNR < 3 { next }  # if file record number < 3, go to next record

NR == FNR {
    # Only the first file's records will be processed here

    # Save info in an associative array.
    aa[$1] = ...

    next  # go on to the next record
}

# If a rule has no pattern, it matches every record
{
    # Only the second file's records will be processed here

    if ($1 in aa) {
        # compare fields
    }
}
```