# Unexpected result comparing values of rows and columns in two text files

Tags: awk, scripting, comparison

This is related to one of my previous question: [How to compare values of rows and columns of two text files in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294876/how-to-compare-values-of-rows-and-columns-of-two-text-files-in-bash)

file1.txt (with special characters: cat -vet file1.txt)

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3^M$  
-----------------------^M$ 
row1  1     4     7^M$         
row2  2     5     8^M$          
row3  3     6     9$
```

file2.txt (with special characters: cat -vet file2.txt)

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3^M$   
-----------------------^M$         
row1  1     4     7^M$ 
row2  2     5     999$
```

I have somewhat figured out a way to compare two files. But for some reason it is not giving me the result that I want. Here is the code I use to compare the files.

```
awk '
FNR < 2 { next }
FNR == NR {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
    {
        a[i,$1] = $i; 
    }    
    b[$1];
    next;

}
($1 in b) {
   for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
   {
      if (a[i,$1] == $i) 
          printf("%s->Col%d: %d vs %d: Equal\n", $1, i-1, a[i,$1], $i);
      else 
          printf("%s->Col%d: %d vs %d: Not Equal\n", $1, i-1, a[i,$1], $i);
   }
} ' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Expected result:

```
row2->Col1: 1 vs 1: Equal
row2->Col2: 4 vs 4: Equal
row2->Col3: 7 vs 7: Equal
row1->Col1: 2 vs 2: Equal
row1->Col2: 5 vs 5: Equal
row1->Col3: 8 vs 999: Not Equal
```

Actual result:

```
row2->Col1: 1 vs 1: Equal
row2->Col2: 4 vs 4: Equal
row2->Col3: 0 vs 7: Not Equal
row1->Col1: 2 vs 2: Equal
row1->Col2: 5 vs 5: Equal
row1->Col3: 0 vs 999: Not Equal
```

Does anyone know why lines 3 and 6 of the actual result are comparing with 0 (not supposed to do so)?

Comment: your script is working fine here. after loading the file1, you can print out all element in the array `a` to see if everything was ok.

Comment: As Kent has already stated that this command works for the given data, you probably need to check your files for any special characters. Do `cat -vet file1.txt` and update your question with the output.

Comment: @Kent I already tried that and the value of each row (except for the last one) doesn't get printed

Comment: @jaypal After executing the command you gave me, I get `^M$` after every line of both files except for the last line (I get only `$`). See update in the question

Comment: @Nosscire Those are control characters for line feed. You created these files on windows environment. Run `dos2unix file1.txt` and similarly for `file2.txt` and re-run your `awk` command.

Comment: @jaypal Thanks a lot it works. +1. If you submit that as answer I will select it.

Comment: @Nosscire You're welcome. You can answer it too. Just add what you did to convert the files and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @jaypal for helping me solve the problem. The problem was that these text files were created in MS-DOS and had to be converted to Unix format in order to be executed in Linux or Unix environment. So before executing the segment of code from the question above, I had to use this command: `dos2unix file1.txt`