# How to check if a row from a text file exists in another text file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, suse

This is a follow up question from: [Unexpected result comparing values of rows and columns in two text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316140/unexpected-result-comparing-values-of-rows-and-columns-in-two-text-files/)

I have created a structure to compare two text files according to their rows and columns. Here are the file structures:

file1.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3 
-----------------------
row1  1     4     7         
row2  2     5     8          
row3  3     6     9
```

file2.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3   
-----------------------         
row1  1     4     7 
row2  2     5     999
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
dos2unix ravi   # 2>/dev/null
dos2unix ravi2  # 2>/dev/null

awk '     
    FNR < 2 {next}       # skips first two lines
    FNR == NR {           
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            a[i,$1] = $i;               
        }    
        b[$1];               
        next;                       
    }

    ($1 in b) {                   # check if row in file2 existed in file1
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            if (a[i,$1] == $i) 
                printf("%s->col%d: %s vs %s: Are Equal\n", $1, i-1, a[i,$1], $i);
            else 
                printf("%s->col%d: %s vs %s: Not Equal\n", $1, i-1, a[i,$1], $i);
        }
    }

    !($1 in b) {                  # check if row in file2 doesn't exist in file1. 
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
            printf("%s->col%d: %s vs %s: Are Not Equal\n", $1, i-1, "blank", $i);
    }

    // pattern needed to check if row in file1 doesn't exist in file2. 

    ' $PWD/file1.txt $PWD/file2.txt
```

Does anyone have any tips, suggestions or hints to have a pattern in the `awk` statement to check if row in file1 doesn't exist in file2. See the sample outputs below to understand what I mean. (ie: Basically, I want to print the values of row3 in file1 doesn't exist in file2). Thanks! Let me know if further explanation is needed.

Desired Output:

```
row2->Col1: 1 vs 1: Equal
row2->Col2: 4 vs 4: Equal
row2->Col3: 7 vs 7: Equal
row1->Col1: 2 vs 2: Equal
row1->Col2: 5 vs 5: Equal
row1->Col3: 8 vs 999: Not Equal
row3->Col1: 3 vs (blank) : Not Equal
row3->Col2: 6 vs (blank) : Not Equal
row3->Col3: 9 vs (blank) : Not Equal
```

Actual Output:

```
row2->Col1: 1 vs 1: Equal
row2->Col2: 4 vs 4: Equal
row2->Col3: 7 vs 7: Equal
row1->Col1: 2 vs 2: Equal
row1->Col2: 5 vs 5: Equal
row1->Col3: 8 vs 999: Not Equal
```

Comment: You should probably use a little python script for this but that's just my two cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending your answer:

```
$ cat script.awk 
FNR < 2 { next }       # skips first two lines
FNR == NR {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { a[i,$1] = $i }
    b[$1];
    next;
}
($1 in b) {                   # check if row in file2 existed in file1
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (a[i,$1] == $i)
            printf("%s->col%d: %s vs %s: Are Equal\n", $1, i-1, a[i,$1], $i);
        else
            printf("%s->col%d: %s vs %s: Not Equal\n", $1, i-1, a[i,$1], $i);
    }
    delete b[$1];   # delete entries which are processed
}

END {
    for (left in b) {   # look which didn't match
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
            printf("%s->col%d: %s vs (blank): Not Equal\n", left, i-1, a[i,left])
    }
}
```

Run it like:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file1 file2
row1->col1: 1 vs 1: Are Equal
row1->col2: 4 vs 4: Are Equal
row1->col3: 7 vs 7: Are Equal
row2->col1: 2 vs 2: Are Equal
row2->col2: 5 vs 5: Are Equal
row2->col3: 8 vs 999: Not Equal
row3->col1: 3 vs (blank): Not Equal
row3->col2: 6 vs (blank): Not Equal
row3->col3: 9 vs (blank): Not Equal
```

Comment: @jaypal I appreciate the time you spent in coding this (so +1) but it still isn't printing `row3` for any column.

Comment: @Nosscire Make sure they don't have any control characters. I just tested this and it works fine with your given data.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that each row "name" (first column) will appear in each file at most once then you could `delete b[$1]` at the end of the `($1 in b)` block, move the `!($1 in b)` block above it, and then add an `END` block that loops over everything left in `b` and prints out your lines.

```
END {
    for (r in b) {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            printf("%s->col%d: %s vs %s: Are Not Equal\n", r, i-1, $i, "blank");
        }
    }
}
```